# Detecting .net application cold or hot start

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to measure startup time of my .net WPF desktop application, however the startup time vary a lot depending if it is a cold or hot start. I would like to separate the times of hot and cold starts so I can build better statistics. Is it possible somehow to detect hot and cold starts?

.net framework 4.8 without ngen, without MultiCoreJit profile optimizations. Appication is installed with MSI installer.

Edit:

#### Cold start

Start after Windows OS reboot, no clr runtime dlls are loaded in physical memory

#### Hot start

The application was closed and immediately started again. clr runtime and eventually some of the application dlls are still loaded in OS memory so no IO occurs, only address mapping to process address space.

This is how I explain to myself why there is a difference in startup time. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Define hot and cold start.

Comment: You will need to update your question with details about how your application is hosted - is it a console app, Winforms, a website running on IIS, a REST API running on Kestrel behind an nginx, a Blazor client application, an AWS Lambda worker, etc? You will also need to define what you mean by a "hot" and "cold" start and how you are currently testing your application to time it.

Comment: Also if ngen/crossgen or .net native is used, what version of .net is used, and if the application is installed, or something like click once is used.

Answer (score 0):

Persist the start and stop times of the application. Define a time window between last stop time and next start time that makes it obvious whether you're doing a hot/cold start. (Note this window is not measuring the startup time at all).

For example, pick a 2 second window. A cold start requires a reboot, so it will be obvious that last stop will be much more than the 2 seconds before the next start.

You could persist these values via a script, or by changing your app to log it's start time as early as possible before any other activity, and its stop time as late as possible while app is shutting down.